# Obtaining the correct path to a resource file in my project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have translated a piece of C# code that is referencing a resource in a namespace path, something which VB doesn't exactly replicate.

The translated code is as follows:

```
Dim path As String = ThemesPath & "Dark.vssettings"
 Using stream As Stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(path)
                If stream IsNot Nothing Then
                    AmbientHighlightingStyleRegistry.Instance.ImportHighlightingStyles(stream)
                End If
            End Using
```

In my Project I have folder Called 'Resources', which in turn contains a folder called 'SyntaxEditor' which contains the Dark.vssettings file.

I would like to declare ThemesPath as a string constant but am having trouble getting the syntax right such that the code within the Using statement can find the Dark.vssettings file.

I tried the following which I thought would do the trick but it doesn't.

```
 Public Const ThemesPath As String = "Resources/SyntaxEditor/"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`Application.StartupPath` returns the folder for the program running from within the VS project. You can parse back up the path and come down to Resources. Only works while running under VS of course. Typical path: `C:\DevVS2010\_Misc_Projects\_TestApp\TestApp\bin\Debug`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is also related to wrong slashes...

Try this code:

```
    Public Const ThemesPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\SyntaxEditor\"
```

Good luck.